# How to create same Radial Gradient in Flutter as provided with css?

Tags: css, flutter, radial-gradients

I have design in Figma, one of the blocks has a background color which is copied as a css radial-gradient. I am kinda new to Flutter and not very familiar with gradients in general, how could I calculate what properties do I need to set for Flutter Radial Gradient to replicate this?

```
background: radial-gradient(112.56% 76.57% at -12.56% 61.25%, rgba(223, 228, 241, 0.23) 20.57%, rgba(223, 228, 241, 0.03) 100%)
```

As far as I understood I need to provide colors and stops which are double values for each color.

```
RadialGradient(
      colors: [Color.fromRGBO(223, 228, 241, 0.23), Color.fromRGBO(223, 228, 241, 0.03)],
      stops: [0,2057, 1]);
```

But I struggle to determine how to define a position, which radius it needs to be, so output is close to this values.

```
112.56% 76.57% at -12.56% 61.25%
```